# undefined is not an object (evaluating...)- React Native

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, components

I have data (called imageNumber and i) coming from another screen to this screen. I have done everything asynchronously but it still gives me an error in the component as undefined and I can't for the life of me figure out what's the problem with the code.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import { DynamicCollage } from "react-native-images-collage";
import { LayoutData } from "react-native-images-collage";

const photos = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551316679-9c6ae9dec224?w=800&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562569633-622303bafef5?w=800&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503656142023-618e7d1f435a?w=800&q=80",
];

export default CollageScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { imageNumber, i } = route.params;
  const [key, setKey] = useState();
  const [numberOfImages, setNumberOfImages] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const collageRef = useRef(null);


  // const NumberOfImages = 3;
  // const index = 3;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const numberOfImages = await imageNumber;
        const key = await i;
        setKey(key);
        setNumberOfImages(numberOfImages);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
          {loading ? (
            <View>
              <Text>loading...</Text>
            </View>
          ) : (
              <DynamicCollage
                ref={collageRef}
                direction={LayoutData[numberOfImages][key].direction}
                width={"100%"}
                height={400}
                images={photos}
                matrix={LayoutData[numberOfImages][key].matrix}
                separatorStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, backgroundColor: "#323031" }}
                containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#f1f1f1" }}
                // imageFocussedStyle={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
                imageSwapStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#323031" }}
                imageSwapStyleReset={{ color: "red", backgroundColor: "red" }}
              />
          )}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
  },
});
```

here is the full code regarding the screen and this is the error given

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeImagesCollage.LayoutData[{
numberOfImages: numberOfImages
}][{
key: key
}]')

This error is located at:
in Unknown (at SceneView.tsx:122)
in StaticContainer
in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Card.tsx:538)
in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
in StackNavigator (at CollageStackScreens.js:11)
in CollageStackScreens (at SceneView.tsx:122)
in StaticContainer
in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at BottomTabView.tsx:55)
in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:171)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:68)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:63)
in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:165)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at src/index.native.js:123)
in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:145)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:144)
in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:45)
in BottomTabNavigator (at MainStackScreens.js:141)
in Unknown (at SceneView.tsx:122)
in StaticContainer
in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Card.tsx:538)
in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:620)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:613)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:495)
in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
in StackNavigator (at AppStackScreen.js:15)
in Unknown (at App.js:14)
in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:13)
in UserProvider (at App.js:12)
in FirebaseProvider (at App.js:11)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
- node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue

- [native code]:null in flushedQueue
- [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

```
direction={ numberOfImages && LayoutData[numberOfImages][key].direction}
matrix={numberOfImages && LayoutData[numberOfImages][key].matrix}
try the above null check
```

Comment: tried it and this time it gives me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'matrix.reduce')

Comment: What is LayoutData?

Comment: haven't imported it in the sample code but it pretty much looks like this

Comment: const LayoutData = {
  1: [
    {
      direction: "column",
      matrix: [1],
    },
  ],
  2: [
    {
      direction: "column",
      matrix: [1, 1],
    },
    {
      direction: "row",
      matrix: [1, 1],
    },
  ],

Comment: try LayoutData[numberOfImages][0].matrix .      replace key with 0 because you will get an array with one object after LayoutData[numberOfImages]

Comment: it still throws me the same error. I think the problem is that the component is trying to load before the data comes in, although it shouldn't be a problem as I used the useEffect hook. but I'm not sure